# Imprimir todas as cartas do baralho (Java)

Tags: java

Olá.

Estou tentando criar um programa que imprima todas as 52 cartas do baralho, do 1 até o 10 e com todos os naipes (Paus, Ouros, Copas, Espadas) e também imprimir as cartas Valete, Dama e rei.

Achei o uso do "for" mais apropriado nesse caso, porém não tenho muito conhecimento com funções de repetições, gostaria de saber como imprimir uma "String" utilizando o "for"?

Estou utilizando essa lógica mas ela não é prática, pois eu teria que criar um "for" para cada número, preciso de uma lógica que simplifique isso.

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i) {
        System.out.println(i  +  " De Paus");
    }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei se foi na hora de copiar aqui, mas tem muitos fecha colchetes ali.

Eu te recomendaria estudar arrays, pensa neles como um conjunto de variáveis, ao invés de ter um valor int na variável tu tens um array (conjunto) de 13 ints dentro desse array.

Tu pode ter um array de naipes e depois disso usar o for para fazer o que tu fez, ou um array de naipes, sendo que cada item é outro array para as cartas.

Depois tu pode percorrer esse array (chamamos de iterar no array) para imprimir.

Segue um link com uma referência inicial para ti ter como base, conteúdo do [DevMidia](https://www.devmedia.com.br/trabalhando-com-arrays-em-java/25530)

Comment: Certo, obrigado ! Vou dar uma estudada..

Comment: @CésarAugusto se der certo não esquece de aceitar a resposta como correta, é importante para outras pessoas que venham a ter dúvidas semelhantes no futuro

Comment: Farei isso.. Mas uma dúvida, nesse link ele está criando o Array com "int" , se eu quiser criar um Array de naipes eu não teria que guardar como "String" ?

Comment: Arrays podem ser do tipo que tu quiser, pode ser um array de int, String, se tu quiser um Array de Arrays, isso é o que chamam de Matriz

Comment: Entendi, no caso de um array de String essa seria a forma correta de declarar ?

String[] naipesCartas = {"Copas,Ouros,Espadas,Paus"};

Comment: Uma String é limitada pelas aspas, então o correto é usar `String[] naipesCartas = {"Copas","Ouros","Espadas","Paus"}`, assim tu tens 4 strings sendo passadas pro teu array, no teu exemplo tinha apenas uma string, com o conteúdo sendo o nome dos 4 naipes.

Comment: Quando for escrever código usa um ` antes e depois do código para ficar mais legível.

Comment: Perfeito ! Estou conseguindo criar uma lógica com base no material que você me enviou, não é tão difícil, obrigado pela ajuda !

Comment: De nada, a comunidade está aqui para isso, ajudar quem está começando, qualquer dúvida sinta-se à vontade aqui no Stack Overflow